# jquery uncheck back the checked box

Tags: jquery, html

here is a piece of copied code and i made some changes. the thing is that i just wanted  to    know how do i uncheck back the checked box which before uncheck all the checked boxes.
    Below is the code:

#html#

```
<html>
<table id="tab1"><tr><td>   
<input type="checkbox" name="book" id="book" value="book1" class="check">book1

<input type="checkbox" name="book" id="book" value="book2" class="check">book2

<input type="checkbox" name="book" id="book" value="book3" class="check">book3

<input type="checkbox" name="book" id="book" value="book4" class="check">book4 

<input type="checkbox" name="book" id="book" value="book5" class="check">book5 

<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll" class="uncheckall">to uncheck
</td></tr></table>
</html>
```

#Jquery#

```
$('#tab1 .uncheckall').click(function(){
if($('.uncheckall').is(':checked')){
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
}  
else {
    $('#tab1 .check').click(function(){
        $('.unckeckall').prop('checked', false);
    }); 

}

});

How to uncheck the 'touncheck' box when other remaining boxes are checked back?
you can check here [http://jsfiddle.net/420/pzCcE/345/]
```

Comment: Why not just use a button to uncheck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled uncheckall, and you can use the `change()` event instead of `click()`, to make it work for keyboard / mobile users as well.

```
$('#tab1 .uncheckall').change(function(){
    if($('.uncheckall').is(':checked')){
        $('.check').prop('checked', false);
    }  
});

$('#tab1 .check').change(function(){
    if($(this).val())
        $('.uncheckall').prop('checked', false);
});
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/pzCcE/347/

(I also noticed the name of the uncheckall checkbox is `checkall` - this is very confusing... would advice to change that as well)

Comment: thanks peter :) for pointing my mistake and for the information that i couldn't notice and also i notice that else was also the problem it was also needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.uncheckall').click(function(){
   if($('.uncheckall').is(':checked')){
        $('.check').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
$('.check').click(function(){
    $('.uncheckall').prop('checked', false); // misspelling here. 
});
```

Your class selector is misspelled.Instead of 'uncheckall' it was unckeckall.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9zxxgnq0/

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

**1)** You have a typo there should be  `uncheckall` instead of `unckeckall` while unchecking the uncheckall.

**2)** You are just checking on `click` of `uncheckAll` so it doesn't check for other checkboxes. I made it to check on click of all checkboxes.

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    if($('.uncheckall').is(':checked')){
        $('.check').prop('checked', false);
    }  
    else {
        $('#tab1 .check').click(function(){
            $('.uncheckall').prop('checked', false);
        }); 

    }

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/pzCcE/352/)

Answer (score 0):

Use change instead:

```
$('#tab1 .uncheckall').change(function(){
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
});
$('#tab1 .check').change(function(){
    $('.uncheckall').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzCcE/357/) (code shorten)